# How to build the latest version of Quartz.net Server from the GitHub repository using NAnt?

Tags: github, build, nant, quartz.net

Unfortunately, I'm just beginning to use "NAnt" and I'm having a hard time building the latest version of Quartz.Net from the GitHub repository using "NAnt".

Once I got the "quartznet-master.zip" from GitHub and extracted its content, I tried running the provided "NAnt.exe" in the root folder where the "Quartz.build" file is located.

It complained about missing references.  I found out the referenced nuget packages were missing.  I then installed the missing packages using the provided "nuget.exe".

Tried "NAnt.exe" again.

It complained about a missing "quartz.net.snk" file (which is normal).

I generated the missing file using "SN.exe" and retried "NAnt.exe".

Now it complains about a field "Barrier" used like a type inside "RAMJobStoreTest.cs".

See below:

> > [csc] c:\Users\xxx\Downloads\quartznet-master\quartznet-master\src\Quar
> >     tz.Tests.Integration\RAMJobStoreTest.cs(41,40): error CS0118: 'Quartz.Tests.Inte
> >     gration.AbstractSchedulerTest.Barrier' is a 'field' but is used like a 'type'

There must be an easier way to build Quartz server using the provided "Quartz.build" file without fiddling with the source code.

I'm probably not using the right target and arguments.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your patience. I've fixed the aforementioned build issues you've described. There's now also a Build.cmd file as shorthand for building.

- nuget restore is done before build if needed
- NET 4 checks are made for tests that rely on Barrier
- Build.cmd as shorthand

The only thing needed now is to manually generate the snk file that you already did.

Comment: I'll try that!  Thanks for the great product and support!